# Continuity Properties of Pseudoinverse with Orthogonal Block

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, pseudoinverse, set-valued-analysis

Let $p$ be a parameter taking values in a compact set $P$. Let $M(p) = \begin{bmatrix} A(p) & D \\\\ B & C\end{bmatrix}$ be a block matrix. Further impose that $A(p)$ is an orthogonal matrix for every parameter value $p \in P$, and that $A(p)$ is Lipschitz inside $P$.

Questions:

1. Is the pseudoinverse $p \mapsto M(p)^+$ continuous?
2. If it is not continuous, is it lower semi-continuous, and does it have a continuous selecton?
3. Does there exist a continuous (possibly non-unique) map from $p$ to the nullspace of $M(p)$?

Prior knowledge:

- The Pseudoinverse of a matrix is generically not continuous in its entries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)
- There exists an explicit formula for the pseudoinverse of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix [Blockwise Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62249/blockwise-moore-penrose-pseudoinverse), https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379575901184
- Orthogonality of $A(p)$ implies that the upper block $[A(p), \ D]$ has full row rank.
- If $A$ is constant in $p$, then $M(p)$ is constant and the pseudoinverse is therefore continuous in $p$.

Comment: It's not clear what lower semicontinuous would mean for a matrix-valued function

Comment: Lower Semicontinuous in the sense of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-4848-0, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358021/how-to-show-that-a-set-valued-function-is-lower-semicontinuous